# search is not working inside viewpager fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, menu, android-viewpager

[Score Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ4dj.png)  [Detail page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3JXp.png) 
I have a Fragment inside view pager. I am implementing the search using menus inside that Fragment. The Search is working fine when I am on current fragment, but when I click on any item on the list it goes to the next activity. Now the problem is when I came back to fragment and trying to search query it Doesn't work.

Comment: Hi! Can you edit your question and add more information? ...maybe the relevant part of your code, or a screenshot of your view.

Comment: @Andrej  i have two screens.one is Score screen and other is Detail Page.Search is working fine when i am on score screen,but when i click on any item inside score screen  and control goes to detail page and when i return back to score screen then i am unable to search matches.i am using menu for searching.